# Is there a way to manually specify the coordinates of a region?

Tags: mcedit

I'm trying to clear out a large region in the Nether to build a gold farm, and I'm really struggling with the GUI. I know exactly the regions I want to specify (`x/y/z`) and the filters I need to run, but with all the crap in the nether, it's extremely difficult to get the GUI to select the entire box.

Is there a way I can just specify the `X/Y/Z` coordinate ranges of the region I wish to filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold down your mouse when the cursor is over those `Nudge` buttons and press <kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd>/<kbd>Q</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd> (navigation controls) to "nudge" the corresponding selection box.

The blue one nudges the blue corner, yellow one nudges the yellow corner, white one nudges the full selection box, green one nudges the selected blocks.

There is really no easy way to specify coordinates, but with this function you can simply select the rough area and then move the corners to select the area you want to select.

Comment: Ugh.  But, it did work!

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing 0. It pulls up the debug mode, and the coordinates of the block that's highlighted are at the beginning of the second line.